# Show that $\widetilde{u} \in PSH(\Omega)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables, potential-theory

**EDITED**

I'm reading the book:

> **(Oxford science publications._ London Mathematical Society monographs,
>   new ser., no. 6) Maciej Klimek -Pluripotential theory -OUP (1992)**.

[image: Problem]
[image: Proof]

- I don't understand **proof** for **Theorem 2.7.1**! Can anyone explain it?
- *Example*:

1/ Why $\boxed{(\sup_{\epsilon >0}u_\epsilon)^*=\widetilde{u}}$?

2/ Why $(\sup_{\epsilon >0}u_\epsilon)=u \in \Omega \setminus F$.

3/ *Why can we suppose that $v<0$ in $\Omega$.*

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that 
$$\sup_{\varepsilon > 0} u_\varepsilon = 
\begin{cases} u, & \text{on $\Omega \setminus F$} \\ -\infty, & \text{on $F$}\end{cases}
$$

Since $u$ is subharmonic (and hence upper semicontinuous), the upper semicontinuous regularization, $(\sup_{\varepsilon > 0} u_\varepsilon)^* = u$ on (the open set) $\Omega \setminus F$. For points in $F$, it's just the definition of the usc regularization $(\cdot)^*$.

Comment: Thanks **mrf**! In my book, I read a **theorem**: *Let $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A} \subset SH(\Omega)$ be such that its upper envelope $$u=\sup_{\alpha \in A}u_\alpha$$ is locally bounded above. Then the usc regularization $u^*$ is subharmonic in $\Omega$.* It's the definition of the usc regularization, I forgot it, hihi! Thank you very much.

Comment: But I don't understand Why can we suppose that $v<0$ in $\Omega$?